# file download from Iggrid

Tags: c#, jquery, infragistics, ignite-ui

I have a datasource bound to iggrid in which statement column data returns link

a href=E:\FILES\STATEMENTS\DAILYSTATEMENTS\20150127\R-956-10103.pdf

Code is as follows

```
$(function () {
       var data = <%= GetAccountInformationJSON() %>;


        if ( data != '' )
        {
            $("#gridAccountInformation").igGrid({
                height: ((content_height - HeaderHeight) / 2) +"px",
                width: "100%",
                columns: [
                    {headerText: "Account", key:"Account", dataType: "string"},
                    {headerText: "Office", key:"Office", dataType: "string"},
                    {headerText: "Balance", key:"Balance", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "Init Mrg", key:"InitMarginReq", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "OTE", key:"OpenTrdEqty", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "Total Eqty", key:"TotalEqty", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "Liq. Val", key:"LiquidatingVal", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "Ex/Def", key:"ExcessDeficit", dataType: "number", format: "0#,###"},
                    {headerText: "Statement", key:"Statement", dataType: "string"}
                ]
                ,

                features:[
                     {
                         name: "Resizing",


                     }

                ],
                dataRendered: function (evt, ui) {

                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(1)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(2)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(3)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(4)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(5)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(6)").css("text-align", "center");
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(7)").css("text-align", "center");  
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(8)").css("text-align", "center");   
                    ui.owner.element.find("tr th:nth-child(9)").css("text-align", "center");
                }
                ,
                dataSource: data //JSON Array defined above   

            });

            $("#gridAccountInformation").igGrid("option", "datasource", data);
        }

    });
```

In the above iggrid, Stmt will be displayed as link.
On clicking it, i need to download the file that is present in datasource.

ex : a href=E:\FILES\STATEMENTS\DAILYSTATEMENTS\20150127\R-956-10103.pdf

clicking on the above should download the file R-956-10103.pdf

Any help would be appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```js
//Delegate
$(document).delegate(".selector", "iggridcellclick", function (evt, ui) {
    //return cell html element in the DOM
    ui.cellElement;
    //return row index
    ui.rowIndex;
    //return row key
    ui.rowKey;
    //return col index
    ui.colIndex;
    //return col key
    ui.colKey;
    //return reference to igGrid
    ui.owner;
});
 
//Initialize
$(".selector").igGrid({
    cellClick: function(evt, ui) {...}
});
```

from:
http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.2/
and then go to "Events" tab

Comment: Tomer Klein - how to call this event from iggrid

Answer (score 0):

The file should be accessible through the web so I suppose it's actually not a physical location like `E://etc`... but something like `http://file.location/filename.pdf`. So if the location is accessible, then does the data source carry the string `href=http://file.location/filename.pdf` or just the location? I assume it's the second one. So you can use a column template to render the anchor:

```
{
    headerText: "Statement", 
    key:"Statement", 
    dataType: "string",
    template: "<a href='${Statement}'>Download</a>"
}
```

I notice something else. You don't need to use `dataRendered` in order to apply CSS to the igGrid headers. You can just use CSS for that:

```
<style>
    ui-iggrid tr th {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is the scenario. The files are present in my local drive ( E:\) and the data source output itself has anchor tag with the path. so when it binds to grid, the last column will be a hyperlink. I believe i do not need add any template. However, when i click on link, it doesn't open the pdf in a webpage eventhough the file exists. Any clue on this ?

Comment: The browser doesn't provide the document access to your file system. Thus the file would not open. You can point to the file as a relative location from where your page is located: ../../FILES/STATEMENTS/DAILYSTATEMENTS/20150127/R-956-10103.pdf (that's if the page is two folders deep in E://, otherwise if it's on C:// you cannot access the file)